# Generating display elements with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5, twitter-bootstrap

I've been writing a modular sandbox that has a web front end. Modules are discovered with reflection and could have parameters to them. When parameters are presented to the UI, I pass them through a set of JavaScript utility methods that map them to display elements which utilize Bootstrap 5 for styling.

```
function createDisplayElementForParameter(parameter) {
    var displayElement = undefined;
    var container = createContainer(parameter);

    switch (parameter.displayElement) {
        case DisplayElement.Checkbox: displayElement = createCheckbox(parameter); break;
        case DisplayElement.Slider: displayElement = createSlider(parameter); break;
        case DisplayElement.Textbox: displayElement = createTextbox(parameter); break;
        case DisplayElement.RichTextbox: displayElement = createRichTextbox(parameter); break;
        default: displayElement = createTextbox(parameter); break;
    }

    if (displayElement != undefined)
        container.appendChild(displayElement);

    container.classList.add("mb-3");
    return container;
}

// Display Elements
function createHelpText(helpID, helpText) {
    var container = createContainer();
    container.id = helpID;
    container.classList.add("form-text");
    container.innerText = helpText;
    return container;
}
function createCheckbox(parameter) {
    var container = createContainer();
    container.classList.add("form-check");

    var inputID = "de-cb-" + parameter.name;
    container.appendChild(createInput(inputID, "checkbox", "form-check-input", undefined));
    container.appendChild(createLabel(parameter.requestMessage, inputID, "form-check-label"));
    return container;
}
function createSlider(parameter) {
    var container = createContainer();

    var inputID = "de-rng-" + parameter.name;
    var helpID = inputID + "-help";
    var range = createInput(inputID, "range", "form-range", helpID);
    range.setAttribute("min", parameter.minValue.toString());
    range.setAttribute("max", parameter.maxValue.toString());
    range.setAttribute("step", "1");

    container.appendChild(createLabel(parameter.displayName, inputID, "form-label"));
    container.appendChild(range);
    container.appendChild(createHelpText(helpID, parameter.requestMessage));
    return container;
}
function createTextbox(parameter) {
    var container = createContainer();
    var inputID = "de-tb-" + parameter.name;
    var helpID = inputID + "-help";
    container.appendChild(createLabel(parameter.displayName, inputID, "form-label"));
    container.appendChild(createInput(inputID, "text", "form-control", helpID));
    container.appendChild(createHelpText(helpID, parameter.requestMessage));
    return container;
}
function createRichTextbox(parameter) {
    var container = createContainer();

    var inputID = "de-rtb-" + parameter.name;
    var helpID = inputID + "-help";
    var richTextbox = createInput(inputID, "textarea", "form-control", helpID);
    richTextbox.setAttribute("rows", "3");

    container.appendChild(createLabel(parameter.displayName, inputID, "form-label"));
    container.appendChild(range);
    container.appendChild(createHelpText(helpID, parameter.requestMessage));
    return container;
}

// Natural Elements
function createContainer() {
    var container = document.createElement("DIV");
    return container;
}
function createInput(id, type, bootstrapClass, describedBy) {
    var input = document.createElement("INPUT");
    input.id = id;
    input.setAttribute("type", type);
    input.classList.add(bootstrapClass);

    if (describedBy != null && describedBy != undefined)
        input.setAttribute("aria-describedby", describedBy);

    return input;
}
function createLabel(innerText, forID, bootstrapClass) {
    var label = document.createElement("LABEL");
    label.setAttribute("for", forID);
    label.classList.add(bootstrapClass);
    label.innerText = innerText;
    return label;
}
```

- What are some negative impacts of this implementation?
- Are there any hidden gotchas?
- What are some things to think about as I expand this to support more elements?
- For example `select`, `file` etc.

Feel free to view the live version of this code [here](https://galacticsandbox.azurewebsites.net/). You'll have to click `Modules` in the nav bar, then select a module (AES Cryptography and Display Element are two good ones for parameter testing), and the details page will appear which utilizes the code in this post to display parameters. There are a lot of items that I have to rewire today due to the recent style changes I made, but it's for a better user experience overall, so I'm okay with it.